# can a esp32 use matter protocol without a hub (apple, alexa, google home, etc)?

Tags: arduino, iot, esp32, sensors, alexa-skills-kit

I don’t have any Alexa, google home, or apple devices that support Matter. I would like to use my ESP32 as the hub, and I would like to use matter because of its easy device/sensor onboarding experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, Espressif even has an [SDK for Matter](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-matter/en/latest/esp32/introduction.html#espressif-matter-solutions), with a pretty good documentation. For WiFi devices, the "normal" ESP32 SoCs are enough, if you also want to support Thread devices you will need to use ESP32-H2 as well.